# How to correctly write number ranges?

Tags: punctuation

Suppose I would like to write something like: "She has between 1-5 cookies on her at all times."; what is the correct way to write such a number range in TeX?

Is it:

```
$1$-$5$
```

Or:

```
$1\text{-}5$
```

Or something else entirely? To me, both of the above seem clumsy.

Comment: `1--5` is OK for me.

Comment: This depends on specific language rules. In German, for example, it is usual to write the numbers as their words, i.e. `one to four` (eins bis vier), but from `5`, the figure is used. I would not tag this question as `hyphenation` ...

Comment: Using "between" in connection with a range sounds weird to me to start with really. I'd say "between 1 and 5" "she has 1 - 5 cookies" (with a strong preference for the former)

Comment: @Christian Swiss German? Because in Austrian/German German the rule I learned was 0-12 written out (as well as "round numbers" such as one hundred). Although [the duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/schreibung-von-zahlen) says that's antiquated.. oh well. Anyhow to make this less off-topic: Independent which method you use when writing number ranges, you should in any case use the en-dash `--` and not the hyphen `-`!

Comment: @Voo? Did I say Swiss German? No.

Comment: @Christian Well considering that the authoritative source for German clearly specifies that the only existing rule is 1-12 with the remark that it's only a custom any more, it's clearly not a common rule in Germany (or Austria at that either)..

Comment: @Being a native German speaker, I don't care about the 'authoritative' source. I was told in school and saw it the same way later on, to use number words for ranges between 1 and 4, however, using the words for enumerations eins, zwei, drei... zwölf, in this sense, we agree (to some extent)

Comment: In spanish there are not tradition of use of --, so there are rules only for - and ---. For the range one should use  the hyphen. Said that, for readability I always use the en-dash for ranges in spanish texts (and nobody complained).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Why not go the SI way ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  This is a range from  \numrange{1}{10}.
  This is a range from  \numrange[range-phrase = --]{1}{10}. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is some more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[detect-none]{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase = \text{--}}
\begin{document}
  This is a range from  \numrange{1}{10}.

  This is a range from  $\numrange{1}{10}$.

  This is a range from  $\SIrange{1}{10}{}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really see how you could mention such a kind of range number in math mode (except with $\text{...}$ of course), nor the use of using `siunitx` if you define the separator locally.

Comment: @anderstood I just meant that you could use {\numrange} in text mode and in math mode, IF you have a scenario where that would be necessary, of course. {\SIrange} is of course more likely to turn up in math mode, if you are using temperature ranges for instance. It obviously depends on your document, but chances are, you can use SI elsewhere in your document, so IF the package is already included, why not use it. And of course you need not define the seperator locally.

Comment: Does that switch to maths mode in the middle of text, though? That seems to me wrong unless the numbers are really mathematics. But maybe that is not what this does - or not the first case, anyway.

Comment: @cfr That one is possibly for Joseph Wright! :)

Comment: @BMWurm @Harish Kumar: for my second point you perfectly answered. For my first point, I still don't see examples where you could need to use number ranges in math mode. For example, I understand that you can use both `$\alpha\SI{3}{\meter}$` and `it measures \SI{3}{\meter}`, but when it comes to number ranges, it seems to me that you should not be in math mode... In maths, dedicated non-ambiguous notations already exist ({1,...,3} or [1,6]\cap\mathbb{Q} or whatever).

Comment: @anderstood My point was... well, it can be used in math mode also if need be. And where is the need? It is up to the user/OP ;)

Comment: @HarishKumar: OK, as far as I'm concerned I'll stick to the "1 to 10" solution :D

Comment: I don't mean to come across as a stickler for English syntax, but I don't think that either "between 1--10" *or* "between 1 to 10" are correct. The expression should be "between 1 **and** 10". Are you maybe thinking of the expression "from 1 to 10", which could also be written "from 1--10"?

Comment: @Mico I agree. I copied that sentence from Anderstood and never thought of grammer ;)

Comment: To out-stickler the sticklers, "from 1--10" is also bad. "x--y" is "from x to y," so "from 1--10" is "from from 1 to 10." For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Dates_and_numbers

Answer (score 8):

Why use math mode? I would do as suggested [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) and write

```
She has 1 to 5 cookies on her at all times.
(She has between 1 and 5 cookies on her at all times.)
```

From wikipedia (Dash article):

> Various style guides (including the Guide for the Use of the
>   International System of Units (SI) and the AMA Manual of Style)
>   recommend that when a number range might be misconstrued as
>   subtraction, the word "to" should be used instead of an en dash. For
>   example, "a voltage of 50 V to 100 V" is preferable to using "a
>   voltage of 50–100 V". Relatedly, **in ranges that include negative
>   numbers, "to" is used to avoid ambiguity** or awkwardness (for example,
>   "temperatures ranged from −18°C to −34°C"). It is also considered poor
>   style (best avoided) to use the en dash in place of the words to or
>   and in phrases that follow the forms from … to … and between … and
>   ….[13][14]

Comment: The grammar doesn't seem to make sense to me :/ Wouldn't you write "She has 1-5 cookies" or "between 1 and 5"? "Between 1 to 5" sounds weird.

Answer (score 6):

In LaTex, the hyphen used for ranges like pages of a book, etc. is referred to as an `en-dash` and is best written as:

`She has between 1--5 cookies on her at all times.`

It is also possible to use the math mode as follows but the first approach is preferable:

`She has between $1$--$5$ cookies on her at all times.`

Or:

`She has between $1\textup{--}5$ cookies on her at all times.`

For nontechnical writing, though, the best approach is to use `to` to avoid any ambiguity.

The result of the above three approaches is as follows (and are identical):

[image]

Comment: If you use another font for normal text and math mode for the numbers you'll have a strange format.

Comment: @Sigur-- That is why I mention it second. But in some cases, especially in technical documents where large number of equations and numbers is used, it is preferable to use the same style in math and text modes for consistency. For example, we should write `the term $2 x$` in equation... and not  `the term 2 $x$` in equation...

Comment: If you have to convert your document to Word at some point, it creates needless complications. (All the maths becomes images and you have to go through and remove them all.)

Answer (score 6):

Neither option is correct, for several reasons.

1. "Between 1–5 cookies" reads as "between one to five cookies", which doesn't make sense. You mean either "Between 1 and 5 cookies" or "1–5 cookies".
2. Most style guides for English recommend writing small numbers (less than ten, twenty or a hundred, depending on who you ask) in words, rather than in figures, when you're talking about a number of objects.
3. Most style guides recommend using an en-dash (`--` in (La)TeX) for number ranges, not a hyphen (`-`).